# Spark InProcessLauncher not picking up Hadoop config

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I'm trying to submit a cluster-mode spark 2 application from a Java Spring app using [InProcessLauncher](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/launcher/InProcessLauncher.html). I was previously using the [SparkLauncher](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/launcher/SparkLauncher.html) class, which worked, but it fires up a long-lived SparkSubmit java process for each job, which was eating up too many resources with lots of jobs in play.

My code sets `sparkLauncher.setMaster("yarn")` and `sparkLauncher.setDeployMode("cluster")`

I set the `HADOOP_CONF_DIR` env variable to the directory containing my config (yarn-site.xml etc) before starting my Spring app, and it logs that it is picking up this variable:

```
INFO  System Environment - HADOOP_CONF_DIR = /etc/hadoop/conf
```

Yet when it comes to submitting, I see `INFO  o.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.RMProxy - Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032` - i.e. it is using the default 0.0.0.0 rather than the actual ResourceManager IP, and of course it fails. It seems not to be picking up the Hadoop config.

I can submit jobs from the same shell directly using `spark-submit`, and even by directly invoking `java -cp /usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/conf/:/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/jars/*:/etc/hadoop/conf/ org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit ...`. So I'm not sure why my Spring App isn't picking up the same config.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get my app to pick up the hadoop config by adding the conf folders to the classpath. This is something `spark-submit` does for you when launching as a separate process, but doesn't happen when using InProcessLauncher.

Because my Spring Boot app is launched using `-jar xxx.jar`, I couldn't use `-cp` on the command line (cannot be combined with `-jar`), but had to add it to the manifest in the jar. I did this by adding the following to `build.gradle` (which is using the Spring Boot gradle plugin):

```
bootJar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Class-Path': '/usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/conf/ /etc/hadoop/conf/'
    }
}
```